# Javascript Binding to C# Not Working

Tags: c#, data-binding, knockout.js, chromium-embedded

I am attempting to create a WinForms application in which the UI is developed in HTML and displayed using Cef. As part of this I want to display some data from a C# class by using binding. To help with the binding I am using KnockoutJS.

I have a JavaScript ViewModel which is able to call my C# code, however there seems to be a problem with the JavaScript not been able to access the array which is returned from C#. I suspect I am missing something which will allow the JavaScript ViewModel to understand the C# StaffDetails class.

I have included my code below, can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

JavaScript ViewModel:

```
function StaffDetails(details)
{
    var self = this;    
    self.firstname = ko.observable(details.firstName);
    self.surname = ko.observable(details.surname);
}

function StaffDetailsViewModel()
{
    var self = this;    
    self.staffDetails = ko.observableArray([]);    
    self.populateStaffDetails = function ()
    {
        //I think this is where problem occurs
        var mappedStaffDetails = $.map(ModelService.getStaffDetailsArray(), function (item)
        {
            return new StaffDetails(item);
        });

        self.staffDetails(mappedStaffDetails);
    }

    self.populateStaffDetails();
}

ko.applyBindings(new StaffDetailsViewModel());
```

C# Model:

```
public class StaffDetailsModel
{
    private List<StaffDetails> staffDetailsList = new List<StaffDetails>();

    //Items added to staffDetailsList within constructor.

    public StaffDetails[] GetStaffDetailsArray()
    {
        return this.staffDetailsList.ToArray();
    }
}
```

StaffDetails Data Class:

```
public class StaffDetails
{
    private string firstName = String.Empty;
    private string surname = String.Empty;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return this.firstName; }
        set { this.firstName = value; }
    }

    public string Surname
    {
        get { return this.surname; }
        set { this.surname = value; }
    }     
}
```

The ModelService used within the ViewModel is added to my Cef WebView as follows:

```
staffDetailsWebView.RegisterJsObject("ModelService", new StaffDetailsModel());
```

Comment: I don't think that you can reliably marshal an instance of a class from the C# runtime into the CEF javascript environment. Typically what I do is return a JSON string. So your StaffDetails class could have a ToJson() method that serializes the the class to a JSON string and passes it to CEF, then use JSON.parse() to construct an object.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to match most if not all of the examples I have found. I would have preferred to be able to be able to use the C# class directly in the JavaScript but it doesn't look like this is possible. I think I will have to switch over to JSON as you have suggested, thanks again.